# how do i know my OpenCL kernel is running on the GPU?

Tags: opencl, gpu

How can I be 100% sure that my opencl kernel are actually running on the GPU and not on the CPU. I am not able to understand this because openCL kernel can also run on CPU. Any pointers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating the command queue with [clCreateCommandQueue](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateCommandQueue.html), then you pass in a `device`. This will be the device that is used for the kernels that are enqueued to this queue.

Whether or not this is a GPU can be found out with with [clGetDeviceInfo](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html), by querying the `CL_DEVICE_TYPE`. It will return one or a combination of

```
CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR
CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT
CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM
```

These are by the way the same types that you are passing to [clGetDeviceIDs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDs.html) when you obtain the device IDs in the first place. So you might want to restrict this query to `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU` right at the beginning, so that you will only obtain the device IDs of GPUs.

Comment: I agree.  Also, to actually witness the effect, you can also observe the GPU spike with a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (select "System Information" (Control+I) / Select the GPU tab).

Comment: thanks for replay, i used amd system monitor same as process explorer when run simple c code such as while(1){printf("hello \n");} the gpu usage is reach from 5 to 90% with out any opencl code only simple c .

Comment: when run opencl program such that sobel edge detection for gray img withou process only show input and output the frame per secounds fps=70 but when process down to 20 (process using gpu ) can have any idea about that

Comment: @user1848223 Sorry, I think I did not understand the last question. It sounds like the frames per second are 70 when you are not computing anything, but 20 when you perform a computation. Any computation takes *time*, so this would not be surprising. Maybe you can try to re-formulate this, possibly as a new question with more information.